# How to interpolate if/else statements with Underscore.js and HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, underscore.js, haml, interpolation, underscore.js-templating

I'm trying to get if/else interpolate working with Underscore.js and HAML, but to no avail. I'm already changing the interpolate setting in Underscore.js to the following:

```
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate : /\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g
};
```

This works nicely when I'm trying to interpolate a value inside a notation like {{ value }}. However, I'm failing to make if/else statements work. I have the following:

```
{{ if (true) { }}
  {{ val }}
{{ } }}
```

I get an Javascript exception "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if ". Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Underscore templates use three different sets of delimiters:

1. `evaluate`: This is for bits of JavaScript, `<% ... %>` by default.
2. `interpolate`: This is for dumping the contents of a variable, `<%= ... %>` by default.
3. `escape`: As `interpolate` but also escapes HTML, `<%- ... %>` by default.

These mostly match ERB syntax. You're trying to use the interpolation syntax with JavaScript that isn't an expression:

```
{{ if(true) { }}
```

but that won't work as an `if` isn't an expression in JavaScript.

You probably want to override all three patterns:

```
_.templateSettings = {
  evaluate    : /\{\{([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g,
  interpolate : /\{\{=([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g,
  escape      : /\{\{-([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g
};
```

and then say things like this:

```
{{ if (true) { }}
  {{= val }}
{{ } }}
```

If you can limit your templates to simple substitutions then you could just use `interpolate` and `{{expr}}` in your templates.